# preserving leading spaces in strings in the database

Tags: sql, db2

I want to insert a column with value ' abcd'

I am using DB2 database.

The query I am using is:

```
insert into mySchema.myTable value (' abcd');
```

However, the space character at the front of the value is getting automatically trimmed when I am fetching the value back from the table.

The query I am using to fetch back the row is:

```
select full_record from mySchema.myTable;
```

How to preserve this leading space in the database?

Comment: The first space should not be trimmed, what is your query to get the value back?

Comment: insert into mySchema.myTable value (' '+' '+'abcd'); or use concat function.

Comment: (Not OP) My DB2 version is iSeries V6R1, and it's preserving both leading and trailing spaces on `VARCHAR` fields.  The manual doesn't seem to list anything applicable to the situation.  But why are you attempting to preserve _leading_ space, anyways?  That's usually more display-related, not something to be stored.

Comment: hmm, my db2 is not supporting 'value' it has to be spelled 'values'. is it a typo on your side, or are you using a different db2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all working fine:

```
Database server        = DB2/SUN64 9.1.9

db2 => create table tt (a char (10), b varchar(10))
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => insert into tt values('a ', 'a '), (' b', ' b'), (' c ',' c '), ('d','d')
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.

db2 => select a, b, length(a), length(b) from tt

A          B          3           4          
---------- ---------- ----------- -----------
a          a                   10           2
 b          b                  10           2
 c          c                  10           3
d          d                   10           1

  4 record(s) selected.

db2 => select '<'||a||'>', '<'||b||'>', length(a), length(b) from tt

1            2            3           4          
------------ ------------ ----------- -----------
<a         > <a >                  10           2
< b        > < b>                  10           2
< c        > < c >                 10           3
<d         > <d>                   10           1

  4 record(s) selected.

db2 =>
```

EDITH: this is the expected behaviour. char() is fixed length, varchar() is variable length (with maximum), so the length of char() is constant. leading spaces have to be preserved, trailing spaces may be removed in varchar().

Answer (score 0):

In MSSQL it works fine it is not trimmed space after and before value of your fields unless you you can't use Ltrim,Rtrim... Function ... Please tell me which database you are using ??

Comment: Am using DB2 database for the purpose

Answer (score 0):

how did you create your table (DDS or script)? what is the data type of the field?

try defining the field as a `CHAR` data type.

Comment: The datatype of the actual field is varchar(250) and I have created the table using simple create query

Answer (score 0):

In sql server the leading space is preserved when inserted leading space in columns of data type char and varchar. However the trailing spaces are getting truncated automatically.

```
create table TestSpace (firstname char(1000), lastname varchar(100))

insert into TestSpace (firstname, lastname)
select '  123', '  345'
union all
select '123  ', '345  '

select firstname, lastname , LEN(firstname) firstlen, LEN(lastname) lastlen
from TestSpace
```